# Apache Accessing Request Headers and setting the value to a variable

Tags: apache

I am trying to access a request header in the apache config file and then add the value of that header to a variable. I have tried the below:

`MY_VAR  %{HTTP:Athorization}`

and

`MY_VAR  ${HTTP:Athorization}`

I am using apache2

Comment: do you want to edit Header Value?

Comment: No...i just want to store it in the variable and use it for further processing